# PHP Replace [plugin-something] with include_once

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I am fairly new to 'advanced' PHP and i am struggling with this problem for a week now. I have read almost everything on this forum to find a solution, but nothing worked quite well.

I want to get content from a database and replace all text like [plugin-example] with an include_once(example.php)
The reason behind it is to make something similar like a 'shortcode' for a content management system.

I tried several codes, and this one is the nearest to my solution (i think/hope). The problem is that this replaces both [plugins] with only the last match value (slider in this case).

```
<?php 
//get database row
while($page = mysqli_fetch_array($hl_page)){

//regex
$search = "/\[plugin-(.*)\]/";

//get all matches with search
$content = htmlspecialchars_decode("This is my blog 
[plugin-blog] 
And this is my slider 
[plugin-slider]");
preg_match_all($search, $content , $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
$match;
}
enter code here
//get file
ob_start();
include_once(''.$match.'.php');
$replace = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


//echo content from page
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$content);

}?>
```

That code outputs:

textual content
[the include_once('slider.php')] <---should be blog.php
more textual content
[the include_once('slider.php'] <--- this one is good

All help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I have well understand what you are trying to do, a more easy way using `preg_split`:

```
$content = <<<'EOD'
This is my blog 
[plugin-blog] 
And this is my slider 
[plugin-slider]
EOD;

$parts = preg_split('~\[plugin-([^]]+)]~', $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

foreach ($parts as $k => $v) {
    if ($k & 1)
        include_once("$v.php");
    else
        echo htmlspecialchars_decode($v);
}
```

Comment: Little question, can I use multiple different replaces in the same $content here as well? Like say I want to have a shortcode like [container] so that I can place a container in the cms? Is that possible in this method, and where should i start to do so?

Comment: @Saypontigohe: No with this method you can't deal with different kinds of tags. If you want to do that, a `preg_replace_callback`  approach will be more easy. However, you can always use `preg_split` capturing the whole content of the tag and parsing it in a second time to know what to do with it: `\[([^]]+)]` *(in this way, you avoid to create giant strings and useless concatenations)*.

Comment: okay thanks! I will try to implement that as well, and otherwise i will come back ^^. I'm kinda new to preg_replaces and that kind of php. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Saypontigohe: in this case, post a new question, don't continue this one.

Comment: @Saypontigohe: and don't forget that the PHP manual is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Put the replacement inside the foreach loop:

```
foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    //get file
    ob_start();
    include_once(''.$match.'.php');
    $replace = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}
echo $content;
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but the problem is that the 'echo' is shown as much as the content has plugins. I only want to show the full content once, with only the replacements replaced. Thereby i only get 2× [plugin-blog]  now :(

Comment: @Saypontigohe: move `echo` after the loop, see my edit.